# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'head' : dask dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

The dataset I am working with is of 2.13 GB csv file. I have been trying to look into it but even after dividing the data in smaller datasets through columns, ddf.head() function doesn't work and gives the error as "'tuple' object has no attribute 'head'".

Whereas the official website of dask also suggests the same in-built function.

npartitions = 35
shape : (13647309, 48)

Please help

Comment: Please give the exact code you executed and the complete exception returned; ideally a snippet of the data too, so that we can run your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a tuple first separate the elements:

```
(a,b) = ddf
```

Then print their types:

```
print(type(a))
print(type(b))
```

If you are working with a Pandas dataframe or series use:

```
print(a.head())
print(b.head())
```

If you are working with a Numpy array use:

```
print(a[:5,:])
print(b[:5,:])
```